# How can I compile TypeScript to JavaScript with Spring Thymeleaf By Use Commed

Tags: javascript, typescript, spring, spring-boot

```
/d/Project_MIS/AppsListing/AppsListing/src/main/resources/typeScript/remoteMenu.tsx
```

This is my location file TypeScript and I want to compile TypeScript to Js

And this one my src access to remoteMenu.js

```
  <script src="../typeScript/remoteMenu.js"></script>
```

Sorry for my English I am new Spring with TypeScript